# assign php variable to div id and access it using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a list of employees generated dynamically from database, and each employee has got an id, now I want to open a div box on each click with respect to the id's and display their id's in that box.
    I am not able to access that div with respect to the id selected.

```
        include 'connect.php';
$ert=mysql_query("Select * from login_session where bit='0' and date='$date'") or die(mysql_error());
 while($we=mysql_fetch_array($ert)){
                            $employee_id=$we['employee_id'];
 ?>

 <li> <a href="#" data-employee="<?php echo $we['employee_id']; ?>" class="addClass"><?php echo $we['name'];?></a></li>
<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="employee_<?php echo $employee_id; ?>">
            <div class="popup-head">
                <div class="popup-head-left pull-left"><img src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" alt="iamgurdeeposahan"> Gurdeep Osahan

                </div>
                <div class="popup-head-right pull-right">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button class="chat-header-button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> </button>
                                      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Clear Chat</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Email Chat</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                    </div>

                        <button data-widget="remove"  class="removeClass chat-header-button pull-right" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-messages">

            <div class="direct-chat-messages">
                    <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                                <abbr class="timestamp">October 8th, 2015</abbr>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
                    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border">
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Osahan</span>
                        </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                      <img alt="message user image" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                        <div class="direct-chat-text">
                        Hey bro, how’s everything going ?
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-img-reply-small pull-left">

                        </span>
                        <span class="direct-chat-reply-name">Singh</span>
                        </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
                    <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                        <abbr class="timestamp">October 9th, 2015</abbr>
                    </div>
            <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
                    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border">
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Osahan</span>
                        </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                      <img alt="iamgurdeeposahan" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                        <div class="direct-chat-text">
                        Hey bro, how’s everything going ?
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                          <img alt="iamgurdeeposahan" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img big-round">
                        <span class="direct-chat-reply-name">Singh</span>
                        </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <div class="popup-messages-footer">
                <textarea id="status_message" placeholder="Type a message..." rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea>
                <div class="btn-footer">
                <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></i> </button>
                <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> </button>
                <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> </button>
                <button class="bg_none pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> </button>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
<script>
   $(function(){
 $(".addClass").click(function () {
          var var1=$(this).data('employee');
          $('#employee_'+var1).addClass('popup-box-on');
            });

 $(".removeClass").click(function () {
          var var1=$(this).data('employee');
          $('#employee_'+var1).removeClass('popup-box-on');
            });
     })


 </script>
```

Comment: Okay, and what is the question?

Comment: I am not able to access the div with respect to the employee selected

Comment: You should write var var1=$(this).attr('id'); No need to call php variable.

Comment: could you reduce the shown code to the part that is relavant to your question?

Comment: I have reduced the code.

Comment: @GarimaSingh  the code that was posted before , was completing different from what is updated now. is this your same code of file?

Comment: yes.. I have just kept the main functional part that was causing an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly , inside the anchor tag `<a>` with class .addClass , you are using `$we['employee_id']` and then for it's respective box you are using `$employee_id` which is null and it results to an undefined variable error.

You should give the trigger and target selectors a unqiue identifiers , such as for .addClass you can use `data` attributes for appending the data to target something. look below:

```
<a href="#" data-employee="<?php echo $we['employee_id']; ?>" class="addClass"><?php echo $we['name'];?></a>
```

and then for respective box id you can assign a unique id to it something like:

```
<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="employee_<?php echo $employee_id; ?>">
```

and at the end inside javascript / jquery , you can trigger them with the `data` attribute value and by placing the unique identifier we have created for target div. let say `.addClass`'s `data` attribute contains `34`, which is a employee id , and `.popup-box` will have `id="employee_34"` as we need to identify them with something unique and not only numbers.

```
 $(function(){
  $(".addClass").click(function () {
          var var1=$(this).data('employee');
          $('#employee_'+var1).addClass('popup-box-on');
            });
  });
```

at the end you php and html code should look like this:

```
include 'connect.php';
$ert=mysql_query("Select * from login_session where bit='0' and date='$date'") or die(mysql_error());
 while($we=mysql_fetch_array($ert)){
                            ?>
 <li> <a href="#" data-employee="<?php echo $we['employee_id']; ?>" class="addClass"><?php echo $we['name'];?></a></li>
<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="employee_<?php echo $employee_id; ?>">
            <div class="popup-head">
                <div class="popup-head-left pull-left"><img src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" alt="iamgurdeeposahan"> Gurdeep Osahan

                </div>
                <div class="popup-head-right pull-right">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button class="chat-header-button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> </button>
                                      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Block</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Clear Chat</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Email Chat</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                    </div>

                        <button data-widget="remove" id="removeClass" class="chat-header-button pull-right" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-messages">

            <div class="direct-chat-messages">
                    <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                                <abbr class="timestamp">October 8th, 2015</abbr>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
                    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border">
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Osahan</span>
                        </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                      <img alt="message user image" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                        <div class="direct-chat-text">
                        Hey bro, how’s everything going ?
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-img-reply-small pull-left">

                        </span>
                        <span class="direct-chat-reply-name">Singh</span>
                        </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
                    <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                        <abbr class="timestamp">October 9th, 2015</abbr>
                    </div>
            <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
                    <div class="direct-chat-msg doted-border">
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Osahan</span>
                        </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                      <img alt="iamgurdeeposahan" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                        <div class="direct-chat-text">
                        Hey bro, how’s everything going ?
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                          <img alt="iamgurdeeposahan" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img big-round">
                        <span class="direct-chat-reply-name">Singh</span>
                        </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <div class="popup-messages-footer">
                <textarea id="status_message" placeholder="Type a message..." rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea>
                <div class="btn-footer">
                <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></i> </button>
                <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> </button>
                <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> </button>
                <button class="bg_none pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> </button>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

and your javascript code like below:

```
 $(function(){
  $(".addClass").click(function () {
          var var1=$(this).data('employee');
          $('#employee_'+var1).addClass('popup-box-on');
            });
  });
```

and do in this way same for removing the respective box for employee div.

**Note**

As the popup-box div's are multiple and are already inside the dom , you should not use `id` selector for remove trigger , as it will target only first div and not others , use an class for removing the div as well such as `removeBox`

**Update for remove**

For removing the div, don't use id for removing the div , change your remove button to the following:

```
 <button data-widget="remove" data-employee="<?php echo $we['employee_id']; ?>" class="chat-header-button removeClass pull-right" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off "></i></button>
```

and use the below jquery code for removing the div

```
$(function(){
  $(".removeClass").click(function () {
          var var1=$(this).data('employee');
          $('#employee_'+var1).removeClass('popup-box-on');
            });
  });
```

Comment: hi..thanks for your help, but still the div box is not appearing

Comment: Check your browser's console , and tell me which error do you get ? , and are the id's from php appending inside the attributes correctly?

Comment: hey..thanks..Now its working, but i am not able to remove the div on calling the class-"removeClass". I have added the same id as mentioned in the div.

Comment: @GarimaSingh check my answer's update section : Update for remove

Comment: @GarimaSingh check Update for remove section in my answer , it will surely solve your removal problem. If that helped , consider accepting the answer.

Comment: thankyou soo much. Its working now. Can you also tell me how I can access employee id inside the div to fetch data from database related to employee id

Comment: You intend ajax call ? i yes , then do the same way of using `data` attributes and inside jquery use `var employee_id = $(this).data('employee);` , this will give you the id from data attribute

Comment: I haven't coded in AJAX. Can't we use just php to do the same?

Comment: You need to ellaborate bit about , how you want the process of that to be ?

Comment: Hey. Its working. No need. Thanks buddy for your help :)